# Stream mp3's (audio only) from Azure Cloud Storage Blobs via Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, audio, streaming, mp3

I have mp3s stored in Azure cloud storage blobs, I'm trying to use Jplayer to stream them to users (which works) however I'm finding the results inconsistent and Jplayer just stops working when trying to seek

My research leads me to believes that azure blob storage is unseekable and therefore incompatible with browser media stream functionality, which maybe the cause of the inconsistent results I'm getting with Jplayer.

So I'm now wondering if it's feasible to use Azure media services, to stream the mp3s I have in blobs.

I know Azure media services has a lot of focus on encoding media, however I'm not sure if I need encoding to solve my problem with seek-ability.

So my question is, is Azure Media Services a good fit for what I'm trying to achieve, and if so, do I need to invoke the media service encoding functionality to make media streaming work seamlessly across browsers, ie like SoundCloud does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems by changing my blob storage account to the latest version (via code) has seemingly fixed the streaming problem I was seeing in JPlayer and may not need media services at all

```
var credentials = new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey");
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var properties = client.GetServiceProperties();
properties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2013-08-15";
client.SetServiceProperties(properties);
Console.WriteLine(properties.DefaultServiceVersion);
```

However if someone answers the question directly, I'll mark accordingly.

Comment: I updated properties to `2015-02-21`, yet I can't stream my MP3 file using `audio` tag.

Comment: AMAZING! This actually worked, here in 2022. How bizarre that you would have to set this property, because I even (in 2022-07) created a bran new storage account so not dealing with an older one, but it too had no scrubbing ability. How strange this range request ability has to be turned on in such a strange and poorly documented way, also with a version going back 9 years old. @SaeedNeamati why did you pick '2015-02-21'? That may not have been "magic" enough, but again TheGeneral's value "2013-08-15" worked for me

Comment: I don't even remember why. It's very old.